Why does Time Machine settings not see a network drive?
Current backup solution

Macbook Pro 13" (2020) running macOS 14.4.1 Sonoma
Seagate 1TB external USB 3 drive formatted as Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)/Master Boot Record

I would like to migrate to a network backup solution. I currently have a TP-Link Archer AX50 AX3000 Wireless Dual-Band Gigabit Router that supports Time Machine backups over the network. (The router supports drives formatted as FAT32, exFat, NTFS, and HFS+ connected via USB.)
The problem is that Time Machine does not see the drive no matter how I have it formatted. (I am using a Maxtor 300 GB drive for testing so as not to lose my current backups.)
I have tried the following formatting:



Format
Scheme




APFS
GUID Partition Map


APFS (Case-sensitive)
GUID Partition Map


Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
GUID Partition Map


Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)
GUID Partition Map


Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
Master Boot Record


Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)
Master Boot Record


ExFAT
Master Boot Record


Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
Apple Partition Map


Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)
Apple Partition Map



I can access the shared drive via SMB by browsing the Network and connecting to the server using the IP address. When I try to add the drive in the Time Machine settings, it says "No Available Time Machine Destinations".
I have even connected the drive to my MBP via USB and formatted it from within the Time Machine settings then unmounted the drive and connected it to the router; it is still not seen.
Previously on a whim, I had formatted a flash drive to test out if I could get a network backup solution, and that worked (though it was several months back).
What step(s) am I missing that is not allowing Time Machine to see the drive?

From a brief perusal of searches in Google for Sonoma and SMB, nobody is happy about it and it generally doesn't work, or work well. This question at AskDifferent may be helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/465152/unable-to-connect-to-smb-share-on-macos-sonoma-from-windows-but-from-another-mac

Did you enable Time Machine Support on the router’s settings?  See the user manual for details

@Allan Yes. I also tried with authentication on and off.

Also see this Apple Support document for the types of formats supported.

Yeah, I have referenced that page several times trying to get this to work.

You wouldn’t happen to have a) that USB flash to test with again, or b)  a Windows (or Linux) computer you can use to test with?   The idea is to narrow the issue down to the Mac or to the router

I have both. I will try anything at this point.

Try sharing from a Windows machine first. Let’s see where that goes

Just create a share on the Windows machine and see if it shows up in the Time Machine settings?

Use the USB flash for now so you can reformat quickly. Make sure you’re using APFS and GPT (MBR can be flaky)

The router only sees an "EFI" partition that is 1 MB in size. I still turned on the TM in the router and it is still not seen in TM settings.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Older MacOSs had a switch that let them see NFS volumes.  I used this to backup to a drive on a linux machine.  defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1  Not sure if it works on Sonoma.  Currently I backup via netatalk on a linux machine.  This works very well. Let me know if you would like details.

TimeMachine needs Bonjour working, and I wonder if there are issues with the router. There's a helpful app called Discovery (http://www.tildesoft.com) which can show you what's advertised on your network. I'd try checking that and see if there's the SMB advertisement there correctly.

FWIW: I have a Synology NAS. After I set up AutoFS on my Ventura machine, and configured a share on Synology to use as TM backup, I was able to add the Synology share to my Time Machine settings.

@Seamus After some testing (with Allan's help), I believe the problem lies with Sonoma specifically. As mentioned in my post, I was previously able to see a drive via the network and I am beginning to think it was before a recent Sonoma update.

Note: This is not a solution to the problem but provides some insight into what is happening.

I followed the instructions for Quick Apple Raspberry Pi Machine and formatted a hard drive to HFS+ and installed netatalk on a Raspberry Pi 3B clone; everything worked fine.
I went into Time Machine settings and the network drive was recognized and added. Since this was over ethernet, the backup took about 13 hours to complete.
I did try connecting the drive to my Archer AX50 and configured the settings for a Time Machine shared drive. Time Machine did not see the drive. This seems logical since the router shares the drive using Samba/SMB, not netatalk.
Conclusion:
A recent update to macOS Sonoma has broken the ability for Time Machine to see a network drive; this is probably somewhere within the Samba/SMB protocols implemented by Apple.

Could you resolve it? I am having the same problem with my Macbook Air and Archer AX50.

I am having the same problem too. Clearly a MacOS Sonoma issue.

For Posterity, this appears to have been resolved at some point between 14.4.1 and 14.5. But is not in the release notes that I could find. Potentially an unexpected consequence related to another issue.

I'm not sure how. I am still having this problem with 14.6.1 so I will just wait until the next major release to see if it is fixed.

@agarza I am on 14.6.1 and not having this issue. I suspect the issue lies in your config or network.

What hardware are you using and how is your network backup configured?

@agarza I'm on an M1 Max Macbook. Other macs in the house also backup to the same TrueNas share. TrueNas has an option to setup a share as a "TimeMachine" I'm not sure what SMB settings it's enabling on the backend. There's not anything particularly unique about my setup.
